# Query and regex find data

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Hello guys! I try to accomplish the following.
I have a string which is a query string like:

```
let query = "?course_subject=Robotica&course_type=%20C&course_location=%20VIV7&course_teacher=%20Pozna_C_R&course_start_hour=14:00%20&course_end_hour=%2015:50"
```

Which I get with:`window.location.search`

What I try to get back is all the pairs **name** - **value** in an array like:

```
output_array = [["course_subject","Robotia"],["course_type","C"]]
```

And so on.
But I can not figure out how to write the code using regex.
Can someone help me with the code?
**I mention that I do not know the query string which it will come, so I can not search using a name,like:*course_subject* or *course_type***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Have you taken a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams). (this is the link provided by the top answer in the question above. I think the for-of example solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use regex.

First you need to decode uri (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp)

```
let loc = decodeURI(window.location.search);
```

Then you have to remove first character and split string with '&'

```
loc = loc.substring(1).split('&');
```

This will give you something like this:

```
["course_subject=Robotica", "course_type= C", "course_location= VIV7", "course_teacher= Pozna_C_R", "course_start_hour=14:00 ", "course_end_hour= 15:50"]
```

As you can see we only need to split each key with '='. You can do this by looping through each value with for loop but there is Array.map method.

```
let output_array = loc.map(function(value) {
  return value.split('=');
});
```

And the result is:

```
[["course_subject", "Robotica"], ["course_type", " C"], ["course_location", " VIV7"], ["course_teacher", " Pozna_C_R"], ["course_start_hour", "14:00 "], ["course_end_hour", " 15:50"]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let query = "?course_subject=Robotica&course_type=%20C&course_location=%20VIV7&course_teacher=%20Pozna_C_R&course_start_hour=14:00%20&course_end_hour=%2015:50"    
var output_array=[];
    decodeURI(query.slice(1)).split("&").forEach(function (item) {
        output_array.push(item.split("="));
    });
```

should do the job.
slice(1) is for getting rid of ? at the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can first decode your url using `decodeURI` and then `array#split` on `&` and then use `array#map` to `arrayp#split` each string on `=`.

```js
let query = "course_subject=Robotica&course_type=%20C&course_location=%20VIV7&course_teacher=%20Pozna_C_R&course_start_hour=14:00%20&course_end_hour=%2015:50";
var result = decodeURI(query).split('&').map(str => str.split('='));
console.log(result);
```